# Are there non-homeomorphic 3-manifolds with the same Turaev-Viro-Barrett-Westbury invariants?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, qa.quantum-algebra, 3-manifolds, topological-quantum-field-theory, fusion-categories

The Turaev-Viro-Barrett-Westbury invariant of a closed oriented topological $3$-manifold $M$ for a spherical fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ is a number denoted $|M|_{\mathcal{C}}$ computed from (but independent of the choice of) a triangulation of $M$ and $\mathcal{C}$-data labelings.

See the book [Turaev-Virelizier](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-49834-8) (2017) on Section 13.1, and the papers [Turaev-Viro](https://doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(92)90015-A) (1991) and [Barrett-Westbury](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-96-01660-1) (1996).

**Question**: Are there non-homeomorphic closed oriented $3$-manifolds $M$ and $N$ such that $|M|_{\mathcal{C}} = |N|_{\mathcal{C}}$, for all spherical fusion category $\mathcal{C}$?

This [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/259923/34538) by [Meng Cheng](https://mathoverflow.net/users/39342/meng-cheng) provides a formula for $|M|_{\mathcal{C}}$ with $M=L(p,q)$ a [Lens space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space) and $\mathcal{C}=Vec_{G,\omega}$ a pointed fusion category, and shows that it distinguishes $L(7,1)$ from $L(7,2)$, for a good choice of $G$ and $\omega$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked Alexis Virelizier (coauthor of the book mentioned above) by e-mail. Here is his answer (reproduced with his authorisation):

> The answer is yes. See Theorem 1.1 (page 2291) in the following paper
> by Funar: [https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~funar/2013geomtopol.pdf](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Efunar/2013geomtopol.pdf)

[image]

Comment: That's interesting. Is it the case that two 3-manifolds have all their TV invariants isomorphic  if and only if their fundamental groups have the same finite quotients?

Comment: @HJRW The lens spaces $L(7,1)$ and $L(7,2)$ have the same fundamental group $C_7$, but different TV invariants (see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/259923/34538)).

Comment: I notice that Funar actually discusses this question in Remark 1.4 of his paper. (See also the sentence immediately preceding the remark: "We don’t know if the $SU(2)$ Turaev--Viro invariants alone determine already the pro-finite completion of the fundamental group.") It seems worth mentioning that Yi Liu has recently made dramatic progress on the question of profinite rigidity for 3-manifold groups.... (cont'd)

Comment: See especially: https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.03602, https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.09412, https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.01022 .